# Load image onto a window using xlib

Tags: c++, imagemagick, x11, xlib

I've created  window class and i want to insert an image as a background of that window. File formats need to be png. I used XImage of magick++ to load an image. but don't know how to make its as a background of my window. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Create an Pixmap using

```
Pixmap XCreatePixmap(display, d, width, height, depth)
      Display *display; // The display
      Drawable d;       // The Window for which to set the background
```

Create a Graphics Context for the Pixmap

```
GC XCreateGC(display, d, valuemask, values)
```

Draw the XImage to the Pixmap

```
XPutImage(display, pixmap, gc, image, src_x, src_y, dest_x, dest_y, width, height)
        Drawable d; // The Pixmap
        XImage *image; // your XImage
```

Finally set the Pixmap as the window's background

```
XSetWindowBackgroundPixmap(display, w, background_pixmap)
      Display *display;
      Window w;
      Pixmap background_pixmap;
```

Then free all resources no longer needed.

Comment: What should be the value mask and values for the xcreategc if Drawable d is a pixmap?

Comment: Can you provide me a program by drawing image using user data?

Comment: Another option is to use `XCopyArea` to copy one Drawable (Pixmap) onto another (Window).

Comment: @marski: OP was asking about setting a window's background, and the method I outlined has the nice, beneficial side effect, that when resizing a window the background will fill it immediately (tiled). Would be nice if one could specify an origin for the background so that you could have it start some, say (-16,-16) pixels outside the window and extend for the same amount on the other side, and then update it at a low rate when resizing the window. Alas, that's not how things are.